# How does internal array of a viewgroup gets alter and what is the job of mChildrenCount?

Tags: java, android

while trying to add a view into a view group with an index of -1, I ran into a little confusion which I did some google research and asked on stackoverflow, I ran into the answer that if the view index is -1 then mChildrenCount will be the index.

1) My confusion lies where I don't exactly understand why when `mChildrenCount == internalArray.length` then the internal array has to be re-sized?

2) Also, I don't understand what is the function of mChildrenCount?

3) It would be really helpful if someone can explain to me what exactly happens to the internalArray or View[] when a view is added and removed and how does mChildrenCount play in this process?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, ViewGroup might have its own view.
So, ViewGroup might contain 10 View in Array but just 7 Views are its child because 3 views are its own view.